Worst Case And Average Case
I am a Ph.d Student
I would like to understand deeply the worst case and average case complexity for my Ph.d purpose, any advices or title of books/lectures would be helpful and thanks in advance
What do we mean by this is an average case problem (What its relation with distribution?)
the same question about Worst-case average case?
